# Understanding the Comma Category $(1 \downarrow K)$ for $K : D \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician* pg. 76:

[image]

**Problem:** I'm having considerable trouble following what the author means by the comma category $(1 \downarrow K)$:

1. What is $1$? The 1-element category? Or the identity functor on $D$?
2. Why does the author say the objects take the form $(d,x)$ of elements $x \in K(d)$. Doesn't he mean $x = K(d)$?
3. Is this meant to be a coslice category, or a [general comma category of this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#General_form)? I'm assuming it's the latter, but am then confused then as arrows don't take the form of tuples of arrows from $D$.

I guess I'm looking for the precise definition of what the author means by the comma category of $(1 \downarrow K)$ (in the format of the wikipedia article I linked to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility you've overlooked is that $1$ refers to the terminal object of $\mathbf{Set}$. Or, if you prefer, the functor from the terminal category to $\mathbf{Set}$ that picks out the terminal object.

However, one only really needs to know this if one wants to see how comma categories are connected. The quoted paragraph does goes on to explicitly specify the objects and arrows of a category isomorphic to $(1 \downarrow K)$, and presumably continues entirely in terms of that category.

---

In greater detail, let $F : \mathbf{1} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be a functor from the terminal category to the terminal object $1$ of $\mathbf{Set}$. Let $*$ be the object of $\mathbf{1}$, and $\star$ be the element of $1$.

Then $(1 \downarrow K)$ means $(F \downarrow K)$, and the aforementioned isomorphism associates

$$ (*,1 \xrightarrow{f} K(d), d ) \sim (d, f(\star))$$

Comment: Does it matter which terminal object of $\mathbf{Set}$ (i.e., one element set) is picked out?

Comment: In the framework of the general comma category linked to: I think $(d,x)$ encodes the object $(d,d,f:d \rightarrow K(d))$ s.t. $f$ sends all objects of $d$ to $x$. Carrying this forward, arrows of form $f : d \rightarrow d'$ then encode general comma category arrows of form $(f, g)$ where $g: K(d) \rightarrow K(d')$ and sends all elements of $K(d)$ to $x'$. This then I think completely links $(1 \downarrow K)$ to the general comma category linked to in the wikipedia article. Perhaps this is what the author is getting at? This assumes that $1$ is the identity functor though.

Comment: @user1770201: $d \to K(d)$ doesn't make sense; $d$ and $K(d)$ are from different categories. The key correspondence being used here is the natural bijection between arrows $1 \to S$ and elements of $S$ (where $1$ is a terminal object of **Set**)

Comment: Isn't $d$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ since we're assuming $D$ is small? Technically I should have said $1(d) \rightarrow K(d)$.

Comment: Your "In greater detail.." clarification cleared up my confusion.

Comment: @Hurkyl answer is perfectly correct. It is annoying that Mac Lane uses here $1$ for the "one point set" , while everywhere else he uses $*$. See for ex. page 45 and expecially page 62 exercise 3.