# Trouble in Proof Representing $K : D \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}$ as a Colimit of Hom-Functor

Tags: category-theory

I'm having trouble understanding a piece of notation in the following proof (from *Categories for the Working Mathematician* pg. 76):

[image]

**Question 1:** Is $(1 \downarrow K)$ taken to be $J$ or $J^D$? In the first sentence of the proof, it looks like $J$ is defined to be $1 \downarrow K$. But then later down it is declared that $M$ has "domain" $J^D$, so that $(1 \downarrow K) = J^D$ and $M : (1 \downarrow K) \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}^D$.

**Question 2:** If $(1 \downarrow K) = J^D$, then how does $(d, x)$ encode a **functor** from $D$ to $J$? To my understanding, $(d,x)$ merely encodes an **object** in the category $(1 \downarrow K)$. [See this post for how this is so.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310652/understanding-the-comma-category-1-downarrow-k-for-k-d-rightarrow-math)

Comment: $1\downarrow K$ is taken to be $J$. I'm pretty sure in the definition of $M$, $J^D$ is a typo; $M: J\to \mathbf{Sets}^D$.

Comment: @Hamed yes $J=(1 \downarrow K)$, but I think $M:J^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}^D$ as you can deduce from the definition of $M$ and by looking at the diagram: on the upper right there is a left pointing arrow $f^*$. It should read $f$ and the $J$ in the diagram should be $J^{op}$. What do you think?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't pay attention to covariant/contravariant nature. I think you're right.

Comment: It's strange: I cannot find any list of errata for *Categories for the Working Mathematician*. This is the cannonical text for Category Theory and is very old. It's amazing this error hasn't been noticed before (at least it's not evident it has from googling).

Comment: This section 7 , page 76 in CWM 2nd ed. seems to be full of small typos. It was not present in the first edition

Comment: @magma: Do you notice any other typos that could mislead a reader?

Comment: @user1770201 I also just googled unsuccessfully.

Comment: @user1770201 I also do not understand the eq. $f * x=x'$ inthe 5th line of the Proof. Repeated in the diagram as $f_* x=x'$ They do not seem to make much sense. In general i have not found any typos in CWM, beside these

Comment: @user1770201 did you see my comment to your other related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2310652/19609 ?

Comment: @magma: Yes, I saw it just now.

Comment: @magma: RE: the $f *$ notation, I wonder if the author is borrowing notation that he uses later in the book?

Comment: @user1770201 No $f_*$ and $f *$ are standard notation, defined on page 34. That's why I say they do not make much sense in the above mentioned formulas. If you are new to Category theory, you can now freely download Awodey 2nd ed. and Basic Category theory by Baez: https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/courses/catlogic/awodey.pdf https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375

Comment: @user1770201 I meant: Basic category theory by LEINSTER (not Baez)