# Trouble Showing $\theta$ is Natural in Proof Involving Hom-Functors and Colimits

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 76 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

[image]

This proof has a few typos, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310992/trouble-in-proof-representing-k-d-rightarrow-mathbfsets-as-a-colimit-of). In short, $M : J^D \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}^D$ is actually $M : J^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}$. Moreover, $f$ and $f_{*}$ seem to be used in improper ways.

**Question 1:** Why is $\theta$ natural? The author claims

$$
f(y^{-1}z) = y^{-1}(fz) = y^{-1} z'
$$

But I don't even know how to parse this given $f : d \rightarrow d'$ and $y^{-1}z$ is a natural transformation. The statement $f(y^{-1}z)$ therefore comes off as nonsense to me (even if we take $f$ to be a typo for $f_*$), so I must be missing something.

**Question 2:** Why is $\theta$ "evidently unique"?

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}\require{xy}$I'm going to ignore all of Mac Lane's notation since there are so many typos. Let $K\colon D^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$. An *element* of $K$ is a pair $(d\in D, x\in Kd)$; by the Yoneda lemma, an element $x\in Kd$ is equivalent to a natural transformation $D(-,d) \Rightarrow K$. We can organize the elements of $K$ into a category $\operatorname{el}(K)$ where a map $(d',y) \to (d,x)$ is a map $f\colon d\to d'$ such that $f^*y = x$. We may more succintly write $\operatorname{el}(K) = (1\downarrow K) = (\mathbf y \downarrow K)^{\text{op}}$ (where $\mathbf y$ is the Yoneda embedding $D \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{D^{\text{op}}}$). The definition of maps in $\operatorname{el}(K)$ can be depicted by either of the following triangles:
$$\vcenter{\begin{CD}
1 @>y>> Kd'\\
@| @VV{Kf}V\\
1 @>>{x=f^*y}> Kd
\end{CD}}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\vcenter{\begin{CD}
D(-,d) @>{x=f^*y}>> K\\
@V{D(-,f)}VV @| \\
D(-,d') @>>{y}> K
\end{CD}}
$$

Let $M\colon \operatorname{el}(K) \to \mathbf{Set}^{D^{\text{op}}}$ send a pair $(d\in D, x\in Kd)$ to the representable functor $D(-,d)$, and send a map $f\colon (d', y) \to (d, x)$ to the representable natural transformation $D(-,f)$. There is a cone $\alpha$ from $M$ to $K$, where $\alpha_{d,x}\colon M(d,x) = D(-,d) \Rightarrow K$ is the natural transformation corresponding to $x\in Kd$. Let $L\colon D^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ and let $\beta$ be a cone from $M$ to $L$. For any $d\in D$ and $x\in Kd$, the arrow $\beta_{d,x}\colon M(d,x) = D(-,d) \Rightarrow L$ corresponds (by the Yoneda lemma) to an element $y\in Ld$, which we denote $y=\theta_d(x)$. These assemble into a natural transformation $\theta\colon K\Rightarrow L$.

$\theta$ is unique $\theta_d$ is required to give a commutative diagram as below (where on the left we write out the cones, and on the right we write the elements corresponding to them by the Yoneda lemma):
$$
\vcenter{\begin{CD}
M(d,x) = D(-,d) @>{\alpha_{d,x}}>> Kd\\
@| @VV{\theta_d}V \\
M(d,x) = D(-,d) @>>{\beta_{d,x}}> Ld
\end{CD}}
\qquad\leadsto\qquad
\vcenter{\begin{CD}
M(d,x) = D(-,d) @>{x}>> Kd\\
@| @VV{\theta_d}V \\
M(d,x) = D(-,d) @>>{y}> Ld
\end{CD}}
$$
which says precisely that $\theta_d(x) = y$.

Naturality is left as an exercise; hopefully these notational fixes are sufficient to clear that up for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but I'd like to demonstrate an alternate proof that uses the concept of a [(co)end](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end). (Co)ends are briefly discussed in "Categories for the Working Mathematician", but their extraordinary versatility and usefulness for calculation aren't even remotely demonstrated. ([Weighted (co)limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weighted+limit), aka indexed (co)limits, are also a very useful and under-discussed tool that are very closely related to (co)ends. This result is particularly nice using weighted colimits, but I find (co)ends more convenient to use most of the time.)

To make this self-contained, I'll take a bit of an unusual route to define (co)ends. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a small category, and $T : \mathcal{D}^{op}\times\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be a functor. The end of $T$ is typically written using a notation similar to $\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}T(D^-,D^+)$ where this binds $D$ and (as a personal idiosyncracy) I annotate the covariant and contravariant occurrences as $D^+$ and $D^-$ respectively. The result is an object of $\mathcal{C}$. Dually, the coend is written $\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}T(D^-,D^+)$. As we'll see, ends are limits and coends are colimits, and vice versa: $\mathsf{lim}F \cong \int_{D:\mathcal{D}}FD^+$ and $\mathsf{colim}F\cong\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}FD^+$. Using representability, we can reduce the question of what a (co)end is to what it is in $\mathbf{Set}$ via $\mathcal{C}(-,\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}T(D^-,D^+))\cong\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{C}(-,T(D^-,D^+))$ and $\mathcal{C}(\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}T(D^-,D^+),-)\cong\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{C}(T(D^-,D^+), -)$. This shows (as usual) that we only need to know what an end is in $\mathbf{Set}$ as coends are characterized in terms of ends. Here's the trick: given functors $F, G : \mathcal{D}\to\mathbf{Set}$, *define* $\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathbf{Set}(FD^-,GD^+) \equiv \mathsf{Nat}(F,G)$ where $\mathsf{Nat}(F,G)$ is the set of natural transformations from $F$ to $G$. This can be described as a limit in $\mathbf{Set}$. Though we won't really need it, we get the general case for $\mathbf{Set}$-valued $S$ via Yoneda, $\int_{D:\mathcal{D}}S(D^-,D^+) \cong \mathsf{Nat}(\mathcal{D}(-,=),S)$.

The formula we want turns out to be for $F : \mathcal{D}\to\mathbf{Set}$, $\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{D}(D^-,X)\times FD^+\cong FX$, we just need to prove it. The power of ends becomes clear now:$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{Set}(\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{D}(D^-,X)\times FD^+,=)
& \cong \int_{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathbf{Set}(\mathcal{D}(D^-,X)\times FD^+,=) \\
& \cong \int_{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathbf{Set}(\mathcal{D}(D^-,X),\mathbf{Set}(FD^+,=)) \\
& = \mathsf{Nat}(\mathcal{D}(-,X),\mathbf{Set}(F-,=)) \\
& \cong \mathbf{Set}(FX,=) \\
\end{align}$$
by Yoneda, we have $\int^{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{D}(D^-,X)\times FD^+\cong FX$, and since limits of $\mathbf{Set}$-valued functors are calculated pointwise, this lifts to an isomorphism natural in $X$, i.e. $F \cong \int^{D:\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{D}(D^-,-)\times FD^+$  The first isomorphism is the characterization of coends; the second is cartesian closure of $\mathbf{Set}$; and the last is Yoneda.

To connect this to the category of elements, it's useful to introduce the concept of a weighted colimit. We can define the weighted colimit in $\mathbf{Set}$ in terms of coends via $G\star F \equiv \int^{D:\mathcal{D}}GD^-\times FD^+$. The previous result is then $\mathcal{D}(-,X)\star F \cong FX$. It turns out we can nicely express the weighted colimit in terms of an ordinary (conical) colimit indexed by $1\downarrow G$, i.e. $\mathsf{el}(G)$. In particular, $G\star F \cong \mathsf{colim}(F\circ\pi)$ where $\pi : \mathsf{el}(G) \to \mathcal{D}$ is the projection functor $\pi(D,x) = D$. Proving this is not difficult. A good chunk of Mac Lane's argument is proving this. Alternatively, you could, using my definitions, show that both satisfy the same universal property, i.e. both represent the same functor. The weighted colimit will produce $S\mapsto\mathsf{Nat}(F,\mathbf{Set}(G(-),S))$, and the colimit indexed by $\mathsf{el}(G)$ produces $S\mapsto\mathsf{Nat}(F\circ\pi,\Delta S)$ where $\Delta : \mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}^{\mathsf{el}(G)}$ is the [diagonal functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_functor). If you expand the set-theoretic definition of $\mathsf{Nat}$ for each of these, you will see that they are isomorphic.